# Ledger 24-word seed vs Daedalus/Yoroi 24-word seed recovery process does not generate the same ADAs addresses

Tags: daedalus, yoroi, seed-phrase, recovery

Using a Daedalus/Yoroi wallet with the 24-word seed and a new Ledger Nano S Plus.

I tried to use the 24-word seed to "recover" the (daedalus) wallet in a new Ledger Nano S Plus, (using Ledger live) the addresses were not the same and obviously not the same wallets. So my questions are:

Why are not the same?. If they are BIP39, the result should be the same?

Second, if I use a new Cardano wallet in a Ledger Nano S Plus, later how can I recover the wallet only with the 24-word seed? (Assuming the hardware was lost and the Ledger company was out of bussines). Is there a way to recover the wallet not using Ledger hardware?

Thank you